# How to reference assets relative to the stylus directory instead of the css compile directory?

Tags: css, stylus

Can I define a path that's relative to the stylus file and not to the compiled CSS file.

I try to build a bower package, containing a stylus file that's supposed to be included directly from bowers `components/my-package` folder. How do I reference the assets of my package, so their path is compiled relative to the package folder, instead of relative to the compiled css file.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an option to resolve relative urls](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/executable.html#resolving-relative-urls-inside-imports), it appeared in Stylus 0.34.0.

When you run Stylus, use `--resolve-url` or just `-r` to use it.